# Connecting to SSH fails at random points with a timeout

Tags: ssh

I have a weird issue when connecting to, and using SSH to multiple servers. At random points the connecting phase, or after being connected for a while, the connection times out.

The issue appears both on my Mac and on my iPhone (using the Termius app).

It happens both when using a ssh key or when using a password, but more often when using a ssh key.

The issue only appears when using the office internet. When using 4G from my phone the issue disappears. Using the phone as mobile hotspot connected to the office router works as well, so the issue seems be with our ISP.

I've talked with the ISP's support and there is nothing they can do.

This started happening yesterday, no issues before then.

Here is a connection attempt when using a password to authenticate (IP-address, username anonymized):

```
$ ssh -vvv user@1.2.3.4
OpenSSH_8.1p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019
debug1: Reading configuration data /usr/local/etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 1.2.3.4 is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to 1.2.3.4 [1.2.3.4] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/username/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/username/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/username/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/username/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/username/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/username/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/username/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/username/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.8
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.8 pat OpenSSH_7.0*,OpenSSH_7.1*,OpenSSH_7.2*,OpenSSH_7.3*,OpenSSH_7.4*,OpenSSH_7.5*,OpenSSH_7.6*,OpenSSH_7.7* compat 0x04000002
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 1.2.3.4:22 as 'user'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/username/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /Users/username/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 1.2.3.4
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:aTTwsnW7RYumH3f5rR0UqAsvZM5F2tgP1XQY33CZhTQ
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/username/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /Users/username/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 1.2.3.4
debug1: Host '1.2.3.4' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/username/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/username/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/username/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/username/.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/username/.ssh/id_xmss 
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
ssh_dispatch_run_fatal: Connection to 1.2.3.4 port 22: Operation timed out
```

Nothing appears in the logs on the servers.

Answer (score 0):

These problems are usually caused by an MTU mismatch.

Comment: I doubt you can SCP files in both directions.